# Will configuring a Raspberry Pi as VPN consume a lot of bandwidth when idle?

Tags: internet, vpn

I would like to configure a Raspberry as a VPN using an ethernet cable connected to a router and Open VPN. When no one is using the VPN, i.e. when it's idle, will it consume a lot of bandwidth? My guess is probably not, since then the Raspberry Pi is not doing much, but I don't know how the VPN would work internally.

My apologies for any technical term wrongly used.

Answer (score 1):

> When no one is using the VPN, i.e. when it's idle, will it consume a lot of bandwidth?

No. The bandwidth used is only what is really in use by VPN clients.  There is not a fixed amount reserved just for that, wasted the rest of the time.